# Transferring Joomla Addons from One host to another

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions

Good day/night great minds,

I have a perfectly functional website hosted online at the following url: www.gmaworld.com (malware infected). Unfortunately This site is infected with malware. I am looking to transfer the contents to another setup to get rid of the malware.

My concern however is how to backup/retain the current addons that i have in the current set up so i dont loose them during the new setup.

I have read through most of the migration/upgrade articles for joomla and none seem to mention anything in this regard. If it does help, I am using the shaper_qubic theme.

I will appreciate every bit of advice to help me ensure a successful transfer of my addons.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you are rebuilding your website to eradicate malware, the best course of action is to re-download Joomla and third party extensions from the official websites and start again.

It's possible (by examining the contents of the extension XML install file) to download all the relevant folders and files which you could then zip back into a Joomla install file but this would be a tedious process, likely prone to manual error and possibly still have vulnerabilities if these aren't the latest versions.

To keep a website secure, you should be installing Joomla and third party extension updates on a regular basis. If you have commercial extensions on your website, you'll need to renew your subscriptions in order to have access to updates.

If cost is an issue, then try to replace commercial extensions with free extensions or try to implement features using core Joomla instead. This is often possible when new features are implemented in the core.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative way to retain your extensions is to clean up the malware without rebuilding your site.

The [myjoomla.com](https://myjoomla.com) audit / clean up tool does this quite well and is a much quicker way to recover your website compared to a complete rebuild.

You will probably still need to update Joomla and third party extensions to the latest versions to prevent a recurrence.

Answer (score 0):

You have best free options available and not only that it is super easy to take backup and restore your site anywhere either in localhost or any other webhost. I hope you have access to backend Administrator side
Steps

1. Download Akeeba backup http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/akeeba-backup and install it.
2. Take a backup of your entire site going to components->Akeeba Backup .backup will have extension JPA backup.jpa format. it wont open in normal extractors. To open the zip file follow the next step.
   [image]
3. Download the extract wizard from https://www.akeebabackup.com/products/akeeba-extract-wizard.html . This will help you to extract the backup file in your desktop.

To Clean the website files use kaspersky Internet Security demo version. it cleaned many of my infected files. And do a vulnerability scan installing it in localhost to know where are the loopholes.